# Create categories and multiple subcategories programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

This code show properly category in wordpress admin area. but not showing subcategory.

**I Need to show 3 categories and 3 subcategories for each category?**

This is what I would like to have for each category:

Category A

- sub-category 1
- sub-category 2
- sub-category 3

I have add the following code in wordpress theme's functions.php file:

```
//create the main category
wp_insert_term(

// the name of the category
'Category A', 

// the taxonomy, which in this case if category (don't change)
'category', 

 array(

// what to use in the url for term archive
'slug' => 'category-a',  
 ));`
```

**Then for each sub-category:**

```
wp_insert_term(

// the name of the sub-category
'Sub-category 1', 

// the taxonomy 'category' (don't change)
'category',

array(
// what to use in the url for term archive
'slug' => 'sub-cat-1', 

// link with main category. In the case, become a child of the "Category A"   parent  
'parent'=> term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' )['term_id']

));
```

But I am getting an error:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' in line 57 …

Corresponding to `'parent'=> term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' )['term_id']`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: parse error expecting in subcategory function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you need to get the **parent term id** outside the function, to avoid the error. You can easily do it this way:

```
$parent_term_a = term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given
$parent_term_a_id = $parent_term_a['term_id']; // get numeric term id

// First subcategory
wp_insert_term(
    'Sub-category 1', // the term 
    'category', // the taxonomy
    array(
        // 'description'=> 'Some description.',
        'slug' => 'sub-cat-1a',
        'parent'=> $parent_term_a_id
    )
);

// Second subcategory
wp_insert_term(
    'Sub-category 2', // the term 
    'category', // the taxonomy
    array(
        // 'description'=> 'Some description.',
        'slug' => 'sub-cat-2a',
        'parent'=> $parent_term_a_id
    )
);

// Third subcategory
wp_insert_term(
    'Sub-category 3', // the term 
    'category', // the taxonomy
    array(
        // 'description'=> 'Some description.',
        'slug' => 'sub-cat-3a',
        'parent'=> $parent_term_a_id
    )
);
```

Then you will use for other **2 groups of subcategories**:

```
// For subcategory group of Category B
$parent_term_b = term_exists( 'Category B', 'category' );
$parent_term_b_id = $parent_term_b['term_id'];

// For subcategory group of Category C
$parent_term_c = term_exists( 'Category C', 'category' );
$parent_term_c_id = $parent_term_c['term_id'];
```

… In the same way *(taking care to have **a unique slug for each subcategory**, that mean at all 9 different subcategory slugs)*…

Reference:

- [Wordpress Function Reference: wp_insert_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term)
- [Wordpress Function Reference: term_exists](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)

Comment: Need to add 3 subcategories for Category A.. in others word 3 subcategory for 1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the first quote from the name of the parent category and could account for the parse error, which should be:

```
// the name of the category
'Category A',
```

Edited comment:

```
$parent = term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' );
$termId = $parent['term_id'];

wp_insert_term(

// the name of the sub-category
'Sub-category 1', 

// the taxonomy 'category' (don't change)
'category',

array(
    // what to use in the url for term archive
    'slug' => 'sub-cat-1', 

    // link with main category. In the case, become a child of the "Category A"   parent  
    'parent'=> $termId

));
```

Comment: Error showing in this line ''parent'=> term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' )['term_id']' but i m unable to solve it..

Comment: Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\website.com\functions.php on line 57

Comment: 57 line in function.php is,,, **'parent'=> term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' )['term_id']**

Comment: You could try getting the array before using the value, for example $parent = term_exists( 'Category A', 'category' ); $termId = $parent['term_id']; Then you would use that value in line 57, for example, ''parent'=> $termId

Comment: plz edit and post subcategory part.. i m unable i think i m not understand complete.

Comment: can we add all 3 subcategories in it

Comment: Yes you could use the same code for the other categories, you'd need to substitute 'Category A' for 'Category B' and 'Category C'

Comment: For the sub-categories you could use the same code and substitute 'Sub-category 1' for 'Sub-category 2' and 'Sub-category 3'